# How do I call Nodejs in Windows environment from a Rake task to compile some LESS files?

Tags: node.js, rake, less, albacore

What it is the correct way to call nodejs from a Rake task? I want to compile some LESS files into CSS. I have the cssless compiler installed globally.

Comment: I assume you tagged Albacore because you're on Windows? If that's correct, note it in the question, because the correct answer may depend on it!

Comment: I have node/npm and less installed, but my environment hangs on `lessc` calls. Do you have it working from your plain command line yet? or from the node `>` prompt?

Answer (score 0):

The command line Less compiler invoked with the lessc command should work.

You can start with installing the Ruby version of Less, which make the Less compiler available for Ruby: `sudo gem install less`

Notice that you also will have to install therubyracer (`sudo gem install therubyracer`) if you will get this compiler working (not required when you replace the compiler with the node version).

Now you should be able to run the following command: `lessc -v`. This should output something like that `lessc 1.7.0 (LESS Compiler) [Ruby] 2.6.0` to the console.

After these steps you can run `npm install -g less` which will install the Node Less compiler (and replace the Ruby compiler, both command install the executable on the same location). Now the `lessc -v` command should output the following to the console `lessc 1.7.5 (Less Compiler) [JavaScript]`

Finally you can create a Rake task to compile Less. An example of such as task can be found at: https://gist.github.com/pfig/1969062 and will look like that shown below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'less'
require 'rake'

SOURCE = "."
LESS = File.join( SOURCE, "path", "to", "less", "files" )
CONFIG = {
  'less'   => File.join( LESS, "less" ),
  'css'    => File.join( LESS, "css" ),
  'input'  => "style.less",
  'output' => "style.css"
}

desc "Compile Less"
task :lessc do
  less   = CONFIG['less']

  input  = File.join( less, CONFIG['input'] )
  output = File.join( CONFIG['css'], CONFIG['output'] )

  source = File.open( input, "r" ).read

  parser = Less::Parser.new( :paths => [less] )
  tree = parser.parse( source )

  File.open( output, "w+" ) do |f|
    f.puts tree.to_css( :compress => true )
  end
end # task :lessc
```